# How to convert my out to dataframe type not series

Tags: pandas

How to convert my out to dataframe

```
def new_func(x):
    d1 = (x['response'])
```

`new_func(df)`

```
0    {'bool': False, 'is_doc': True}
1    {'bool': False, 'is_doc': True}

Name: response_dl_back_url, dtype: object
```

if i change to `d1 = df['response']` then also its not working

My Expected out

```
{'bool': False, 'is_doc': True}
{'bool': False, 'is_doc': True}
```

`Basically when calling from the data frame it has to dict type not object`

Comment: `dtypes` of a series cannot be dict, it will be object even if you have a series of dicts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have a string representation of a dictionary, here is one way, we will still need to hold the dictionary in something so I'll nest it within a dictionary.

```
print(df)
   response
0  {'bool': False, 'is_doc': True}
1  {'bool': False, 'is_doc': True}

from ast import literal_eval
d = {}
counter = 0
for x in df['response'].tolist():
    counter += 1
    d[counter] = literal_eval(x)

print(d)
{1: {'bool': False, 'is_doc': True}, 2: {'bool': False, 'is_doc': True}}
type(d)
dict
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

```py
d1 = df['response']  # Series
d1 = df[['response']] # DataFrame
```